# Should I add a regex to a function that opens a file and prints each line with a keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, file, for-loop

I feel like I should be adding a regex somewhere in the loop, but I'm not exactly sure which would best fit this function or how I should properly complete the for loop below.

```
def print_lines(keyword, filename):
  with open('gatsby.txt', 'r') as file:
    sentences = file.read().split('.')
    keyword = input()
    for keyword in sentences: 
      if keyword in filename:
        print(sentences)
```

Comment: Could you add more details of your use case? Regex has many benefits like wildcards and ignoring case that could keep your code simpler, but if you're using user input you would likely shy away from regex and add boilerplate to your code to lower case the string your searching

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What you "should do" is usually a function of what you want your code to do.  You haven't told us what you want this code to do, so how can we know what your code "should do"?  This site isn't about such questions anyway.  This isn't a code review site.  This site is for asking specific technical questions involving programming languages, ideas and tools.  To rework your question to belong here, get as far as you can, then describe the results you want, what you're getting instead, and why you are struggling to understand how to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

The line defining `sentences` expects a certain format for each line (of keywords, I presume), namely there are different words separated by a period. If this is the case, then how exactly would regex be any more useful than the code you already have?

If, on the other hand, your input file were more generic than a bunch of words split by periods, then regex *would* be useful to find particular keywords, provided that you know what to match in the search.